# I want to redirect specific url to non https using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

my current htaccess is:-

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

i want to add rule to htaccess for url like `https://www.example.com/abc/arg1/arg2` should redirect to `http://www.example.com/abc/arg1/arg2`
for this https://www.example.com/abc/* it should redirect to non-https format with keeping all arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Use below rule, check after clearing your cache.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/abc/(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

**Edit:** Please try with below rule,

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/abc/(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

In above rule we are appending https to all url which are not starting with `abc/(.*)` you have to use this `rewritecond` where your original https rule exists.

Comment: Hi it didn't worked. https url is still not redirected to http, i used private window to test this

Comment: @Deejay: Private window doesn't mean old cache is gone. Clear your browser cache completely and retest.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect all https requests starting with `abc/` to http, you must check for both `abc/` and `HTTPS`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^abc/ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

When everything works as it should, you may replace `R` with `R=301` ([permanent redirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301)). *Never* test with [`R=301`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542).

Answer (score 0):

**I am not sure how you achieve the job, but the following should be working perfectly for you.**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/abc [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```